# XML binding to WPF, inline/property binding and filter clauses

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xpath

I'm attempting to bind an XML document to wpf, via datacontext, and am having trouble figuring out how to do property binding

Assuming an xml file like:

```
<Vehicles>
  <Vehicle Name="Test" Vehicle_Id="1"/>
</Vehicles>
```

How do I achieve what I'm attempting below,

attempt 1:

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding XPath=/Vehicles/Vehicle[@Vehicle_Id='1']}" Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
```

attempt 2:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=/Vehicles/Vehicle[@Vehicle_Id='1']/@Name}"/>
```

e.g. is it possible to use filter clauses on the xpath for datacontext

As I'm seriously new to WPF, I accept that I may be completely missing the point of DataContext in this context.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those XPath expressions are valid ones. I assume you are asking your specific XML vocabulary features about XPath engine invocation. Retagging.

Comment: @Alejandro I tagged XPath as it relates to the xpath property of WPF binding.  While they may be correct xpath, neither of the lines above compile when assigned to the xpath property within a property binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try setting up a XmlDataProvider.  Check out [Bea Stollnitz's](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=51) blog for examples of XML WPF XAML only binding methods.